# Pressure transducer being read using LabVIEW

Tags: transducer, pressure, labview

I understand this is not a typical question for this forum, and that the NI LabVIEW forum would be better ([I posted there too](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Reading-output-voltage-from-pressure-transducer/td-p/3829835)), but I am hoping that someone who is proficient in LabVIEW will see this. I am merely an intern seeking help from the seasoned.

I am trying to measure pressure using a pitot tube hooked up to a [MPX2010DP Pressure Transducer](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2291387.pdf?_ga=2.230655071.2124413838.1534440267-810072295.1534440267). The pitot tube is taking the measurements from inside of a duct system.  Pressure is minimal, with PSI being around <1.

The transducer is rated for 25 mV full range output, 10-16 V input, and 0-1.45 PSI. It has a 4 pin connection, 1=GND, 2=V+out, 3=Vsupply, 4=V-out.  I have an external power supply connected to pin 1 and 3.

My problem is that I am unsure on how to exactly and correctly acquire the output voltage of this transducer.

My solution/attempt was to hook up pin 2 and 4 to the analog input of the NI 9215 module (AI2+ and AI2-) to read the output from the transducer.  However, I got meaningless values, with nothing corresponding to the pressure fluctuations. I then tried module 9219 because it has signal conditioning which I need in order to accurately read the mV output. This did not work either.

What am I doing wrong exactly? I thought this would be pretty straightforward but I was very wrong, or perhaps I am overlooking something simple such as calibrations. I simply don't have enough experience at this time to effectively troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be something to keep the common mode voltage within the +/-10V range of the 9215 inputs. The BNC version appears to have a 100K resistor to COM but the spring terminal version does not.

You can connect the negative of your external power supply directly to the COM input terminal, or put a 1K resistor in series.

I would expect both the sensor output pins to sit at about half the supply voltage that is energizing the sensor, so if you're using a 12V supply at about 6V, give or take a few percent. That's well within the common mode range if the negative of the supply is connected to the common of the ADC module.